# Is there a way to initialize an empty slice?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

Something like this?

```
[String, 0]
```

`Vec::new()` is not an option.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This creates an empty array:

```
let thing: [String; 0] = [];
```

You can also get a slice from the array:

```
let thing: &[String] = &[];
```

You can also use `as`:

```
some_function([] as [String; 0]);
some_function(&[] as &[String]);
```

Comment: A neat workaround from a comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092380/5496433 is `[instance; 0]`, e.g., `[0_i32; 0]`, `&[""; 0]`, `[Struct::new(); 0]`. The type of `instance` determines the type of the slice.