# How do I annotate the type of an empty slice in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, assert

Suppose I want to compare a `Vec<String>` to a literal empty list in a test.

(I'm aware that in practice I could check `is_empty()`, but I'd like to understand how Rust typing works here, and I think asserting equality will give a clearer message if it fails.)

If I just say

```rust
    let a: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    assert_eq!(a, []);
```

I [get an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b1085850a5d2146575c307d1c9d0463) that

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     assert_eq!(a, []);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
  |
  = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I think the issue is that rustc can't tell whether I mean an empty list of `String`, or an empty list of `&str`, or something else?

How can I add the needed type annotations onto the `[]` literal?

Does this depend on the [not-yet-stable type ascription feature](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0803-type-ascription.html), or is there a stable way to specify this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach that [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b22bfa54b5039fdb9bddce11ff727c14) today is an `as` cast specifying both the type and the length:

```rust
assert_eq!(a, [] as [&str; 0]);
```

Comment: I would probably arrive quicker to the following workaround, but it feels "much less pure" since we mention an unused value: `[""; 0]`.