# Creating an array of size 0 consumes value, forgetting it

Tags: rust

I stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092178/how-do-i-annotate-the-type-of-an-empty-slice-in-rust), and having read ramslök's comment on the accepted answer, I tried it out with a type that was not `Copy`.

To my surprise it compiled successfully, but it's destructor never ran, effectively forgetting the value, as if `std::mem::forget` was called. Here is a code example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1eb3257ef42ba09efb11c91ccbad4b7)):

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct A;

impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping A");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<A> = vec![];
    let a = A;
    assert_eq!(vec, [a; 0]);
}
```

If we tried to use `a` after the `assert_eq`, it complains the value was moved into the array.

Forgetting values is already possible via the `std::mem::forget`, and it does not cause U.B., but it still feels weird that it's possible without compiler magic.

**My question is**: Is this a bug, or is it an intended feature of rust?

Comment: Note that with an array of size 1, `drop` will be called, and size 2 and above, the code won't compile as `A` isn't copy. Since `Copy` and `Drop` are mutually exclusive it can't cause problems there either. Arrays of size 0 aren't very useful, this might just be an oversight.

Comment: A quick search via godbolt shows that this behavior changed between rustc 1.11 (which displays "Dropping A") and rustc 1.12 (which doesn't display anything).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. Since the array length must be a compile-time constant this is currently not something you would normally write, but with const generics coming, this might actually become relevant at some point. I couldn't find any issue on Github about this yet.

Comment: 1.12 was when MIR code generation was enabled by default. It makes sense that this might have caused this bug.

Comment: I reported the bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74836

Comment: @SvenMarnach as the bug was more or less confirmed, you probably want to add an answer based on your GitHub report.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, `[a; 0]` is intended to evaluate and drop `a`, as described in [Rust's docs for the array type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html):

> Note that [expr; 0] is allowed, and produces an empty array. This will still evaluate expr, however, and immediately drop the resulting value, so be mindful of side effects.